# JavaScript separately the number equal to the corresponding columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td >
            <input type=hidden name="remaining_110" value="19.98">
            <input type="text"  size="8" name="amount_110" value="">
        </td>
        <td  width="16"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <input type=hidden name="remaining_111" value="19.98">
        <input type="text"  size="8" name="amount_111" value=""></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="totalinput">
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="amountinput" size="8" name="" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left"></td>
        <td id="totalsum" align="right">
            <b>39,96</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to put a number at `amountinput` and separately at the inputs above.(`amount_110`, `amount_111`, `amount_112 etc.`amount` will be a static word, the numbers will change )

Like :

> I  set  **amountinput** to the number *30*, 
>           **amount_110** will get *19.98*, 
>           **amount_111** will get  *10.02*

Another one:

> I  set  **amountinput** number 18,
>           **amount_110** will get 18,
>           **amount_111** will get  0 <- or nothing

Does anyone know how?

Update :

```
 $("#clickMe").click( function() {
                        runforest();
                        });
function runforest()
        {
            var IDs = [];
            $("input[name*=\"remain_\"]").each(function()
            { 
            IDs.push([this.name.split(/_(.+)?/)[1],                               $(this).val()]); 
            });
            var tempo = $("#inputsum").val();
            var alloena;

            alloena=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++)
            {
                CallFunction(IDs[i][0], IDs[i][1], tempo, alloena);
                var newone = IDs[i][1];

                alloena = alloena+Number(newone);

            }
        }

        function CallFunction(id, value, tempo,alloena)
            {

         if (alloena<tempo  ){

            console.log("ID: " + id + ", value: " + value + ", new: " + tempo + " alloena : "  + alloena + " emfanizi : " + value);
            }

        }
```

the output is :

```
 ID: 7, value: 22.14, new: 100 alloena : 0 emfanizi : 22.14

    ID: 10, value: 11.69, new: 100 alloena : 22.14 emfanizi : 11.69

    ID: 16, value: 22.14, new: 100 alloena : 33.83 emfanizi : 22.14

    ID: 21, value: 22.14, new: 100 alloena : 55.97 emfanizi : 22.14

    ID: 23, value: 22.14, new: 100 alloena : 78.11 emfanizi : 22.14
```

my problem is at last line .. is add 22.14 but I want to see the remain of the 100-78.11=...

**update solution**

```
    function runforest()
        {
            var IDs = [];
            $("input[name*=\"remain_\"]").each(function()
            { 
                IDs.push([this.name.split(/_(.+)?/)[1], $(this).val()]); 
            });
            var tempo = Number($("#inputsum").val());

            for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++)
            {

                if (Number(IDs[i][1])<tempo ){

            console.log("ID: " + IDs[i][0] + ", value: " + IDs[i][1] + ", new: " + tempo  + " emfanizi : " + IDs[i][1]);
            tempo = Number(tempo) - Number(IDs[i][1]);
            }
            else if (Number(IDs[i][1])<tempo || tempo >0){

            console.log("ID: " + IDs[i][0] + ", value: " + IDs[i][1] + ", new: " + tempo  + " emfanizi : " + tempo);
            tempo = Number(tempo) - Number(IDs[i][1]);
            }
            else {
                    break;
                    }



        }
    }
```

```
ID: 7, value: 22.14, new: 100 emfanizi : 22.14

ID: 10, value: 11.69, new: 77.86 emfanizi : 11.69

ID: 16, value: 22.14, new: 66.17 emfanizi : 22.14

ID: 21, value: 22.14, new: 44.03 emfanizi : 22.14

ID: 23, value: 22.14, new: 21.89 emfanizi : 21.89
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post what you've already tried? This is not a free coding service!

Comment: i update the question.., what you mean isnt free coding service?

Comment: He's just hinting to the fact that this site isn't for requesting people to write code for you, only to ask for help with problems with your existing code.

Comment: mmm but i dont want to write my code someone only to show me how or find better solution etc .. most of the time i dont ask for help .. but now i dint know from which direction to go ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by selecting "amountinput" using JQuery selector & then bind a function to its change event, here is the code :

```
$('#amountinput').change( function() {
    $('[name=amount_111]').val( $(this).val()); // or whatever you want to set it to
    $('[name=amount_110]').val( $(this).val()); // or whatever you want to set it to
});
```

Here is the JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtj4u1e5/8/

For more information :

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/change/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yes one point is that .. but i dont knwo the name of amount  and i want the  JavaScript code separately the money at  table automatically